# Laravel 4 - dynamic tables show/hide data with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-4, mouseover, dynamic-tables

I've created a dynamic table with a `foreach`. And I want to show some data when you 'mouseover' every row, and hide it again when you 'mouseout'. My code:

```
@foreach($actividads as $p)

            <tr id="{{ $p->id }}">
                <td>
                    <table class="table">
                        <td>
                        </td>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="content{{ $p->id }}" class="hidden">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Action</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </div>
            </tr>

@endforeach
```

I would like, when my user 'mouseover' over `<tr id="{{ $p->id }}">`, the `<div class="{{ $p->id }}">` shows its content. And when the user 'mouseout' it, the content is hidden again.

My jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#{{ $p->id }}").on('mouseover',function (e) {
        var mostrar = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#content" + mostrar).show();
    });
    $("#{{ $p->id }}").on('mouseout',function (e) {
        var mostrar = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#content" + mostrar).hide();
    });
});
```

I have some problems calling the 'ids' in my jQuery, because if I try to do that normal ids (not variables), it can work...

I would appreciate any help!! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
@foreach($actividads as $p)

            <tr data-id="{{ $p->id }}" class="myclass">
                <td>
                    <div id="content{{ $p->id }}" class="hidden">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger pull-right">Action</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

...and my jQuery:

```
$(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            var mostrar = $(this).data('id');
            var mostrar_id = 'content'+ mostrar;
            // alert(mostrar_id);
            $("#" + mostrar_id).removeClass("hidden");
        },

        mouseleave: function () {
            var mostrar = $(this).data('id');
            var mostrar_id = 'content'+ mostrar;
            // alert(mostrar_id);
            $("#" + mostrar_id).addClass("hidden");
        }
    }, ".myclass");
```

I hope it can help somebody! ;)